# Adding a number to an HTML button or link (like missed calls/texts on smart phone)

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, notifications, icons

What I want to do is have an image that's clickable that has on top of it a number (number of notifications).

Some common examples are facebook's globe when you have missed notifications or the phone icon on the iphone when you missed a call.

I don't want to re-invent the wheel if possible.

Comment: Have you tried examining the html for facebook's globe?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice

Comment: or tried to examine stackoverflow's?

Comment: Take a look at how Twitter Bootstrap does it (by examining their CSS): http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#labels-badges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the label/link in a div. and insert another div for the bubble with number, style it. make its position absolute but dont set left and top. use marginLeft and marginTop to position. z-index can be used to battle the overlap situations as @nathan mentioned

Comment: Here is what I ended up doing based on your suggestion. Once we get the icons I'll be able to size everything the right way but for now I just wanted some text to test.

Comment: `code` <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Title Page</title>   
   .button {
   width: 80px;
   }
   
   .notification {
   position: absolute;
   margin-left: 75px;
   margin-top: -20px;
   font-size: xx-small;
   width: 120px;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="button">
   <a href="test">Test Button<div class="notification">1</div></a>
  </div>
 </body>

Comment: kind of looks good, I just quickly wrote which looks what you'll want
http://jsfiddle.net/F5Axe/

Answer (score 1):

all you have to do is have an image and a label in the same place but the label that will hold the number would have a greater z-index to be on top